# choose interface parameters in module declaration

Tags: syntax, system-verilog

Let's say I have a parameterized interface, e.g.

```
interface Foo;
    parameter WIDTH=8;
    logic [WIDTH-1:0]data;
endinterface
```

Now I would like to use one of these interfaces with a width of (say) 16 in a module. How can I do this? I tried

```
module foo(Foo #(.WIDTH(16)) in, output logic [15:0]out);
    assign out=in.data;
endmodule
```

but get an error:

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at test.sv(6) near text "#";  expecting ")"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current SystemVerilog syntax BNF does not allow you to specify a parameter specialization of an interface port. It will acquire the parameterization from the instance that get connected to the port

```
module foo(Foo in, output logic [in.WIDTH-1:0] out);
   assign out = in.data;
endmodule          

interface Foo #(
    parameter WIDTH=8
          );
    logic [WIDTH-1:0]data;
endinterface : Foo

module top;
   Foo#(.WIDTH(16)) f();
   logic [15:0] o;
   foo dut(f,o);
endmodule : top
```

You can put an elaboration check for a particular parameterization that will produce a compilation error if the check fails

```
module foo(Foo in, output logic [in.WIDTH-1:0] out);
   if (in.WIDTH != 16) $error("Width not 16");

   assign out = in.data;
endmodule
```

The `if` statement above is not a procedural statement, it is a `generate-if` block

Comment: What can be done if this *is* the top-level module (hence is not instantiated)?

Comment: SystemVerilog has a requirement that interface ports cannot be left unconnected. Perhaps your synthesis tool has a way of specifying the parameters. Otherwise you will have to create an wrapper module above your module.

Comment: @dave_59: Perhaps this is just a simulation requirement? For synthesis, interface ports of the top module can be left unconnected and not instantiated (at least in my examples) just like regular ports. In that case, the default parameter values will be used.